# How to get values from any row in the mutator module after editing table?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm having problems getting the values from the first three rows of table after user edits table.

Table should award points to columns "pts1, pts2,… ptsn" (Points awarded) by matching columns "sp1, sp2,… spn" (selected pilot) and column "ro" (official results).

1.- If "spn" value match "ro" in same row, user gets points from column "po" (official points by pilot's place).

2.- Else if "spn" value is in podium (first 3 rows) then user gets only 2 points for any value that matches and did not met first condition.

3.- Else user gets 0 points.

Column "ro" can be edited by user to make predictions.

Problem:
If table is edited on page by user then mutator will process 1st and 3rd conditions ok, but won't process second condition, so it never awards the 2 points. Console log results in undefine on var podium. This does not happens if "ro" values are loaded so I guess the logic works.

Look everywhere and cant figure this one out, what could I be missing?.

Here is my sample Code:

```
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, ro:'', op: 25, sp1:"HAM", pts1:''},
    {id:2, ro:'', op: 18, sp1:"VER", pts1:''},
    {id:3, ro:'', op: 15, sp1:"BOT", pts1:''},
    {id:4, ro:'', op: 12, sp1:"PER", pts1:''},
    {id:5, ro:'', op: 10, sp1:"RIC", pts1:''},
    {id:6, ro:'', op: 8, sp1:"ALO", pts1:''} // table is only 10 rows first 10 pilots

];


var table = new Tabulator("#pronosticos", {
    height:"310px",
    dataTree: true,
    reactiveData:true,
    data:tabledata,
    dataChanged:function(data){
        document.getElementById("bt-puntaje").style.display="inline-block";
    },
    cellHozAlign:"center",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    columns:[ 
            {title:"POS", field: "pos", formatter:"rownum", width:40, frozen:true},
            {title:"RES PRE", field:"ro", width:70, frozen:true, editable:true, editor:'autocomplete', 
                editorParams: {
                    allowEmpty:true, 
                    showListOnEmpty:true, 
                    values:["ALO", "BOT", "GAS", "GIO", "HAM","LAT","LEC","MAZ","NOR", "OCO", "PER", "RAI", "RIC", "RUS", "SAI", "MCH", "STR", "TSU", "VET", "VER"] // list of pilots to select
                },
                
            {title:"PTS", field:"op", width:40, frozen:true, visible:false},


//          *****************************************    sp1   *****************************************
            {title:"PN", headerTooltip: "Players Name",
                columns:[
                {title:"SEL", field:"sp1", width:50},
                {title:"PTS", field:"pts1", bottomCalc:"sum", width:10,
                    mutator:function(value, data){ 
                        var selected = data.sp1;
                        var winner = data.ro;
                        var podium = [tabledata[0].ro, tabledata[1].ro, tabledata[2].ro]; // Error Undefine if table edited
                        if(selected === ""){
                            return
                        } else {
                            if(podium.length > 0){
                                    if(selected == winner){
                                        return data.op; // This part works ok
                                    } else {
                                        if(podium.includes(selected) && data.id < 4){
                                            return 2; // this part does not work
                                        } else {
                                            return 0;}}}}}

                    
                ]
            },
        ],
    });


    $("#bt-puntaje").click(function () {
        table.updateData(tabledata);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just resolved my issue, was loading a second table in the same page with both the same generic structure. Changed this table's var name from tabledata to tabledata2 and table to table2 and works ok. Tabulator is very nice, excited to learn more about its functionality. Best regards to the creator and to all the community.